# How can I access exported .reg file using batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

I exported registry keys to a `.txt` file using `reg export` command. 
I cannot read this file using `for /f`.

I tried to change code page using chcp command although I didn't get any better.
When I change encoding in exported file using `Notepad++` everything seems to work.

Comment: __access__ the file using batch is very broad... What do you want to access in the file? just see each line? or actually manipulate something? `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type regfile.txt') do echo %%i`

Comment: I would like use it to change some lines. Everything works correctly, only one problem is encoding.  reg export ... >> abc.txt command is making use of UCS-2 Little Endian (UTF-16). After changing it into UTF-8 using external programs everything is OK and I can change something.

Comment: ok, so open `cmd` then run `chcp 10000` and then `for /f "delims=" %i in ('type regfile.txt') do echo %i` and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: use get-content and set-content in powershell.

Comment: Thank you very much
'type regfile.txt' solved the problem

Comment: ok, so you are now sorted out?

Comment: You don't need to export it using `Reg Export`, then perform a conversion, then read it then modify it then merge it again. You can read it directly with `Reg Query` change it then `Reg Add` it. More probably, you could just `Reg Add` your wanted information, _(with the `/F`orce option if you wanted to ensure overwrites of any existing key information)_.